# Timer negativando ao chegar na data final

Tags: javascript, timer

Estou utilizando um timer que está funcionando bem, o único problema é que quando ele zera ele começa a contar no negativo e eu quero que ele fique parado no zero, segue o código:

```
    <script>
   var target_date = new Date("november 27, 2020").getTime();
   var dias, horas, minutos, segundos;
   var regressiva = document.getElementById("regressiva");

   setInterval(function () {

   var current_date = new Date().getTime();
   var segundos_f = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

   dias = parseInt(segundos_f / 86400);
   segundos_f = segundos_f % 86400;

  horas = parseInt(segundos_f / 3600);
  segundos_f = segundos_f % 3600;

  minutos = parseInt(segundos_f / 60);
  segundos = parseInt(segundos_f % 60);

  document.getElementById('dia').innerHTML = dias;
  document.getElementById('hora').innerHTML = horas;
  document.getElementById('minuto').innerHTML = minutos;
  document.getElementById('segundo').innerHTML = segundos;


  }, 1000);
  </script>
```

Como faço pra ele parar no zero e não negativar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples, verifique se a diferença entre o `current_date` e o `target_date` é menor do que zero, se for não execute a lógica e pare o interval:

```js
var target_date = new Date("november 27, 2020").getTime();
var dias, horas, minutos, segundos;
var regressiva = document.getElementById("regressiva");

var intervalRef = null;

intervalRef = setInterval(function () {
  var current_date = new Date().getTime();

  if ((target_date - current_date) <= 0) {
    document.getElementById('dia').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('hora').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('minuto').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('segundo').innerHTML = 0;
    clearInterval(intervalRef);
    return;
  }

  var segundos_f = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

  dias = parseInt(segundos_f / 86400);
  segundos_f = segundos_f % 86400;

  horas = parseInt(segundos_f / 3600);
  segundos_f = segundos_f % 3600;

  minutos = parseInt(segundos_f / 60);
  segundos = parseInt(segundos_f % 60);

  document.getElementById('dia').innerHTML = dias;
  document.getElementById('hora').innerHTML = horas;
  document.getElementById('minuto').innerHTML = minutos;
  document.getElementById('segundo').innerHTML = segundos;


}, 1000);
```